# How to remove SMS and Call permissions from an Android app built with create-react-native-app?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, create-react-native-app

I have a non-ejected android app created with **create-react-native-app**.

Google is requiring those apps to remove CALL_LOG and SMS permissions on its manifest file, but i can't find that file.

How can i set those permissions?

Comment: Curious question why are they required to be removed from the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, add the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myappid"
+   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    ...
+   <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
+   <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

If you want to remove permissions from production APK, then:

1. Create a new directory inside this directory, called release. (path:
   android/app/src/release/)
2. Create an AndroidManifest.xml file. (path:
   android/app/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml)

And add above lines in the `android/app/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`